# Enter Button Not Working Inside Fancybox

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, fancybox

I have a login form inside a fancybox popup and for some reason the submit button doesn't work.

I tried using different html input types as show below.

With `type="button"` the form works but when i click enter is doesnt submit form

With `type="submit"` the form doesnt work at all when i click submit or press enter it just redirects me to `mysite.com/?login=&pass=&submit=SIGN+IN+TO+YOUR+ACCOUNT` closing the fancy box

This below is form code

```
<div style="display:none">
    <div id="sign_in" class="fancybox_message sign_in_popup">
        <div class="login_form_container">
            <h1 class="semibold">SIGN IN TO YOUR ACCOUNT</h1>
            <form>
                <input type="text" name="login" id="login" class="regular" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Username or Email" />
                <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" class="regular" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Password" />
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <div class="squaredFour">
                    <input style="display: none;" type="checkbox" value="None" id="squaredFour" name="check" />
                    <label for="squaredFour"></label>
                </div>
                <span class="regular remember">Remember me</span>
                <a href="#" class="regular forgot">Forgot your username/password?</a>
                <div class="errorHolder" style="float: left;margin-top:5px;color:red"></div>
                <input type="button" name="submit" id="ajaxLogin" class="semibold submit" value="SIGN IN TO YOUR ACCOUNT" />
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="login_social_container">
            <!--<a href="<?php echo $website_domain.'/account/auth.php?pl=facebook'; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $website_domain; ?>/assets/images/login_facebook.png" alt="Login from facebook" /></a>-->
            <a href="<?php echo $website_domain.'/account/auth.php?pl=facebook'; ?>" class="btn facebook">Login with Facebook</a>
            <a href="<?php echo $website_domain.'/account/auth.php?pl=twitter'; ?>" class="btn twitter">Login with Twitter</a>
            <a href="<?php echo $website_domain.'/account/auth.php?pl=linkedin'; ?>" class="btn linkedin">Login with Linkedin</a>
            <a href="<?php echo $website_domain.'/account/auth.php?pl=google'; ?>" class="btn gplus">Login with Google+</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add

```
onclick="submitMyForm()"
```

to the submit button, then implement your ajax operation in a function called **submitMyForm**.

If you're not sure about ajax or don't want to juggle with the fields, you can use a hidden iframe and make your <form> target point there.  This way you get the submitted info just as you normally would but no page reload will happen.